# O que é Lazy, Laziness no Python/Django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Estou começando a programar e lendo a documentação do [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/), vi algumas referências sobre *lazyObject*, sobre o Django ser *Lazy* e que *QuerySets* são *lazy*.

Fiz algumas pesquisas mas não cheguei a um entendimento sobre como funciona *lazy/Laziness* e qual o beneficio disso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No caso das querysets, significa que ela não usa o banco de dados até ser "gasta". O [exemplo](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy) que o próprio django oferece clarifica bem:

```
>>> q = Entry.objects.filter(headline__startswith="What")
>>> q = q.filter(pub_date__lte=datetime.date.today())
>>> q = q.exclude(body_text__icontains="food")
>>> print(q)
```

As três primeiras linhas geram 3 querysets diferentes, mas são apenas instruções que serão executadas tão logo eu percorra a listagem (ou a imprima, como no caso).

Entenda *lazy* neste caso como *atrasado*.

Há outras aplicações deste conceito que são específicas para seus casos. Por exemplo, traduções *lazy* (ugettext_lazy), que são aplicadas em tempo de rendenização da string, ao invés de serem executadas ao chamar a função gettext.

Conforme a [documentação correspondente](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#lazy-translation), isso é útil para garantir que a tradução funciona corretamente a nível de módulo, como ao definir *labels* de campos em modelos ou seu *verbose_name*.

Sugiro uma leitura da [explicação do Django sobre laziness](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/performance/#understanding-laziness).